# React typescript snowpack - can't import .webp

Tags: reactjs, typescript, snowpack

I just started using Snowpack for a React/Typescript project and initialized it with: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@snowpack/app-template-react-typescript. It looks very promising but I get an error `[@snowpack/plugin-typescript]  Cannot find module '../../dummy.webp` or its corresponding type declarations when trying to import a `.webp` image. Somebody an idea how to get it working without using `@ts-ignore`?

Answer (score 1):

Just found the solution. You need to add the following lines in `types/static.d.ts`:

```js
declare module '*.webp' {
  const ref: string;
  export default ref;
}
```